# Bayes Rule and Conditional probability problem

Tags: conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

A new test has been developed to determine whether a given student is overstressed. This test is $95\%$ accurate if the student is not overstressed, but only $85\%$ accurate if the student is in fact overstressed.  It is known that $99.5\%$ of all students are overstressed. Given that a particular student tests negative for stress, what is the probability that the test results are correct, and that this student is not overstressed?

I figure that $A=${accurate test result}, $S=${student is stressed}, and $N=${Negative test result}, so $P(A|S^c)=.95$, $P(A|S)=.85$, and $P(S)=.995$.

I'm not sure exactly what I'm supposed to solve for for. I think I'm trying to solve for $P(A|N)$, and the fact that this student is not overstressed just tells me how accurate the results are. The thing I don't know how to get is any of the probabilities surrounding a negative test result.

I would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: Hint: Don't think of "Accuracy" as an event, but what an accurate results *says* is the event.  When the test is accurate when given a negative result, that says that the student is unstressed. $$\mathsf P(A\mid N)=\mathsf P(S^\complement\mid N) ~=\dfrac{\mathsf P(S^\complement)~\mathsf P(N\mid S^\complement)}{\mathsf P(S^\complement)~\mathsf P(N\mid S^\complement)+\mathsf P(S)~\mathsf P(N\mid S)}$$

Comment: So then, P(N|Sc)=.95?

Comment: Yes, and $\mathsf P(N^\complement\mid S)=0.85$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Accuracy is a compound of the events of test result and stress state.  
It is better not to consider it a seperate event.   Rather think about what an accurate results *says* is about the student when given the result, and vice versa.   When the result is *accurate and negative*, that says that the *student is unstressed*.   When the result is *accurate and the student is stressed* that says that the *result is positive*.

$A=(S\cap N^\complement)\cup(S^\complement\cap N)\\A\cap N=S^\complement\cap N\\A\cap S=S\cap N^\complement\\\ddots\text{et cetera}$

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\mid N)~&=~\mathsf P(S^\complement\mid N) \\[2ex]&=~\dfrac{\mathsf P(S^\complement)~\mathsf P(N\mid S^\complement)}{\mathsf P(S^\complement)~\mathsf P(N\mid S^\complement)+\mathsf P(S)~\mathsf P(N\mid S)}\\[2ex]&=~\dfrac{(1-0.995)~0.95}{(1-0.995)~0.95+0.995~(1-0.85)}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you, this explanation was very helpful. My initial block was that the question asked for the probability that the test results were accurate, and I couldn't connect the accuracy to the result of he test.